# Call Javascript function with parameters from Java program

Tags: java, javascript

I have Java Swing application. When user clicks on MenuItem I want to show graph on HTML page, using JavaScript.
Java code:

```
 if(e.getActionCommand().equals("show graph")){
        if(mainPopulation != null) {
            double[] myPoints = mainPopulation.getElements();
            Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try {
                d.open(new File("D:/fp.html"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

JavaScript code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    function draw(params) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = '10pt Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'; 
        for(i=0;i<params.length;i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(params[i], params[i+1]);
            ctx.lineTo(params[i + 2], params[i + 3]);
            ctx.stroke();           
            ctx.fillText('(' + params[i].toString() + ';' + params[i +1].toString() + ')', params[i], params[i+1]);
            i += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="draw([10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,40,100,50,90,70,90,60,50]);">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I call function **draw**(on **body onload**) with parameter **double[] myPoints**, dynamically change HTML from Java program?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just draw the graph as a Swing control?

Comment: What Java program? A desktop app? An applet? Server-side code?

Comment: @user546252 : A simple desktop app.

Comment: @McDowell : I want to learn how Java interacts with Web technologies.

Comment: Problem solved!
I open html-file as text file and then edit it with BufferedWriter, inserting into function call appropriate parameters.

Comment: That's a lot of work done when you r trying to learn how "Java interacts with Web technologies". Will serve u better if you take some real time eg, as what you have done , nobody is gonna do it that way. And again, as @McDowell mentions , that could have been done as part of swing control itself.

Comment: @The Dark Knight : Thank you.